# Plotting a sum for a series of sine and cosine all within the same height on the x-y axis?

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

The limits of the graph should be (0,1) on the x and y axis but mine is [1,11] on x-axis and [0,7] on the y axis. Any idea what to do?

```
ListLinePlot[
  Table[
    2 π 
      (Sum[
         2 E^(-n^2 π^2 t) π  *  
           NIntegrate[E^(-((1 - Cos[π y])/(2 π))) Cos[n π y], {y, 0,1}] * 
             n Sin[n π x], 
         {n, 1, 10}] / 
           (NIntegrate[E^(-((1 - Cos[π y])/(2 π))) , {y, 0, 1}] + 
              Sum[
                2 NIntegrate[
                    E^(-((1 - Cos[π y])/(2 π))) Cos[n π y], {y, 0, 1}] * 
                    E^(-n^2 π^2 t)* Cos[n π x], 
                {n, 1, 10}])), 
    {t, {0.3, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01, 0}}, 
    {x, {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1}}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the table you made does not depend on x as

```
{{x ,f[x, t]},...}.
```

It is like

```
{ {f [xi , t1 ], ...} , { f [ xi , t2 ] , ...} , ... , { f [ xi , t5 ] , ... }  }.
```

so list line plot take the position number of the function's value in the list to be its x axis. That is why it starts from 1 and goes to 11 on X axis. So modify as follows:

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[{x, 
   2 \[Pi] (Sum[
       2 E^(-n^2 \[Pi]^2 t) \[Pi]*
        NIntegrate[
         E^(-((1 - Cos[\[Pi] y])/(2 \[Pi]))) Cos[n \[Pi] y], {y, 0, 
      1}]*n Sin[n \[Pi] x], {n, 1, 
    10}]/(NIntegrate[
     E^(-((1 - Cos[\[Pi] y])/(2 \[Pi]))), {y, 0, 1}] + 
    Sum[2 NIntegrate[
       E^(-((1 - Cos[\[Pi] y])/(2 \[Pi]))) Cos[n \[Pi] y], {y, 0, 
        1}]*E^(-n^2 \[Pi]^2 t)*Cos[n \[Pi] x], {n, 1, 
      10}]))}, {t, {0.3, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01, 0}}, {x, 0, 1, .1}], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image: plot1]

you can change the option `PlotRange` of the plot from

```
PlotRange->{{0,1},{0,1}}
```

to

```
PlotRange->{{0,1},All}
```

or

```
PlotRange->All
```

to get

[image: plot2]

Comment: @NavinRajil thank you, your answer was helpful